# in Python remember last method called/get

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
inst = AnyClass()
remember_last_method(inst)

inst.foo()
inst.bar()

print inst.last_method # print bar

inst.foo
print inst.last_method # print foo

inst.remember_last_method = False

inst.bar()
print inst.last_method # print foo
inst.remember.last_method = True
```

Any suggestion to write the `remember_last_method` function?

### First edit:

seems that votes are negatives...

Here is the code I started to write, if it can clarify the question:

```
def remember_last_method_get(cls):
    """
    Subclass cls in a way that remeber last method get by instances

    >>> @remember_last_method_get
    ... class Foo(object):
    ...     def bar(self):
    ...         pass
    ...     def baz(self):
    ...         pass
    >>> foo = Foo()
    >>> foo.bar()
    >>> foo.baz()
    >>> print foo.last_method_get
    baz
    >>> m = foo.bar # get a method without calling it
    >>> print foo.last_method_get
    bar
    """
    class clsRememberLastMethodGet(cls):
        def __getattribute__(self,name):
            attr = cls.__getattribute__(self,name)
            if callable(attr):
                self.last_method_get = name
            return attr
    return clsRememberLastMethodGet
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Works on instances and not on classes as I want, and doesn't have the remember_last_method=True/False attribute

### Second edit:

Here is a metaclass that do the job (only for method called, not
get, which is better):

```
class RememberLastMethod(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, d):
        type.__init__(self, name, bases, d)
        for name,attr in d.iteritems():
            if not callable(attr) or name.startswith('_'):
                continue
            def create_new_attr(name,attr):
                def new_attr(self,*args,**kwargs):
                    if self.remember_last_method:
                        self.last_method = name
                    return attr(self,*args,**kwargs)
                return new_attr
            setattr(self,name,create_new_attr(name,attr))
        orig__init__ = self.__init__
        def new__init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            self.remember_last_method = True
            self.last_method = None
            orig__init__(self)
        self.__init__ = new__init__

class AnyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = RememberLastMethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
    def bar(self):
        pass

# Call two method, inst.last_method is the last
inst = AnyClass()
inst.foo()
inst.bar()
assert inst.last_method == "bar"

# Call a new method, changes inst.last_method.
inst.foo()
assert inst.last_method == "foo"

# Stop changing inst.last_method.
inst.remember_last_method = False
inst.bar()
assert inst.last_method == "foo"

# Changing last_method again.
inst.remember_last_method = True
inst.bar()
assert inst.last_method == "bar"

# Work with reference to method as well
method = inst.foo
inst.remember_last_method = False
method()
assert inst.last_method == "bar"
inst.remember_last_method = True
method()
assert inst.last_method == "foo"
```

### Thrid edit:

Here is a function that take an instance as argument and do the same work as the metaclass:

```
def remember_last_method(inst):
    inst.remember_last_method = True
    cls = inst.__class__
    for name in dir(inst):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            continue
        attr = getattr(inst,name)
        if not callable(attr):
            continue
        def create_new_attr(name,attr):
            def new_attr(self,*args,**kwargs):
                if self.remember_last_method:
                    self.last_method = name
                return attr(*args,**kwargs)
            return new_attr
        setattr(cls,name,create_new_attr(name,attr))

class AnyClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass
    def bar(self):
        pass

inst = AnyClass()
remember_last_method(inst)

# Call two method, inst.last_method is the last
inst.foo()
inst.bar()
assert inst.last_method == "bar"

# Call a new method, changes inst.last_method.
inst.foo()
assert inst.last_method == "foo"

# Stop changing inst.last_method.
inst.remember_last_method = False
inst.bar()
assert inst.last_method == "foo"

# Changing last_method again.
inst.remember_last_method = True
inst.bar()
assert inst.last_method == "bar"

# Work with reference to method as well
method = inst.foo
inst.remember_last_method = False
method()
assert inst.last_method == "bar"
inst.remember_last_method = True
method()
assert inst.last_method == "foo"
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want to perform tracing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html).

Comment: Or use decorators. You want something similar to what is described in step 12. http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Comment: What should happen in the following scenario? `method = inst.foo; inst.remember_last_method = False; method(); print(inst.last_method)`

Comment: @Dunes I added your code to the example. Calling the method directly or a reference to the method has the same effect (IMO, that's the right behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this yourself for each method:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_method = None
        self.should_store_last_method = True

    def set_last_method(self, meth):
        if self.should_store_last_method:
            self.last_method = meth

    def store_last_method(self, should_store):
        self.should_store_last_method = should_store

    def one(self):
        self.set_last_method(self.one)
        print("ONE")

    def two(self):
        self.set_last_method(self.two)
        print("TWO")
```

to use it:

```
x = X()

x.one()
# ONE
print x.last_method
# <bound method X.one of <__main__.X object at 0x1035f8210>>
x.last_method()
# ONE
x.two()
# TWO
print x.last_method
# <bound method X.two of <__main__.X object at 0x1035f8210>>
x.last_method()
# TWO
x.store_last_method(False)
x.one()
# ONE
print x.last_method
# <bound method X.one of <__main__.X object at 0x1035f8210>>
```

gives:

```
ONE
<bound method X.one of <__main__.X object at 0x1035f8210>>
ONE
TWO
<bound method X.two of <__main__.X object at 0x1035f8210>>
TWO
ONE
<bound method X.one of <__main__.X object at 0x1035f8210>>
```

Comment: from kecer or Joe reply, maybe writing a metaclass that automatically decorate each method?

Answer (score 0):

A metaclass is definitely the way to go. Your metaclass implementation is a good one, but it falls over in a couple of edge cases. That is there are several things that are callable, but will not be turned into instance methods that can exist on a class. For instance, you might have a `staticmethod` or a `classmethod` or even define a class within the parent class, or most simply an object of a class that has a `__call__` method.

Your function/property implementation avoids these problems, but with the downside of recording these function calls. These functions do not access the object on which can they can be found, so do you really want to be recording them?

I've provided an implementation below. This metaclass only works with Python 3. To convert to Python 2 you must remove the `name` arg from the `__init__` and `__new__` methods on `MethodLoggerMetaclass`. You will also have to use the `__metaclass__` name instead of providing it as an argument on the class declaration line.

```
from types import FunctionType, MethodType
from collections import Callable
import builtins

class MethodLoggerMetaclass(type):
    """Records the last method that was called on a class as the base function
    (called an unbound method in python 2.x)

    By default _last_method is used to record which method was last called.
    Use `class MyClass(metaclass=MethodLoggerMetaclass, name="new_name")' to
    change this behaviour.

    Set record_superclass to True to also record the methods on superclasses.

    Set record_hidden to True to also record attributes beginning with s
    single underscore.

    Set record_callable to True to also record callable objects that are *not*
    instance methods. eg. static methods and class methods."""

    def __init__(self, classname, parents, attributes, name="_last_method",
                 record_superclass=False, record_hidden=False, 
                 record_callable=False):
        type.__init__(self, classname, parents, attributes)
        method_logger_names[self] = name
        if record_superclass:
            for attr, value, needs_self in get_superclass_functions(self, 
                    record_hidden, record_callable):
                type.__setattr__(self, attr, wrap(value, name, needs_self))

    def __new__(metaclass, classname, parents, attributes, 
                name="_last_method", record_superclass=False, 
                record_hidden=False, record_callable=False):
        types = FunctionType if not record_callable else Callable
        for attr, value in attributes.items():
            if record(attr, value, record_hidden, types):
                attributes[attr] = wrap(value, name, isinstance(value, 
                    FunctionType))
        attributes[name] = MethodLoggerProperty()
        return type.__new__(metaclass, classname, parents, attributes)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        """Used to wrap functions that are added to the class after class
        creation."""
        if isinstance(value, FunctionType):
            type.__setattr__(self, attr, wrap(value, 
                             method_logger_names[self], True))    
        else:
            type.__setattr__(self, attr, value)


class MethodLogger:
    """Used to record the last method called on a instance. Method stored as
    base function. Has convenience properties for getting just the name or as a
    method, or the unwrapped function.

    Calling the provided function or method will also record the call if record
    is set to True."""

    _function = None
    record = True

    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

    @property
    def function(self):
        return wrap(self._function, method_logger_names[type(self.instance)])

    @function.setter
    def function(self, function):
        if self.record:
            self._function = function

    @property
    def unwrapped_function(self):
        return self._function

    @property
    def method(self):
        if self._function:
            return MethodType(self.function, self.instance)

    @property
    def name(self):
        if self._function:
            return self._function.__name__

    def __str__(self):
        return "MethodLogger(instance={}, function={}, record={})".format(
            self.instance, self._function, self.record)
    __repr__ = __str__

class MethodLoggerProperty:
    """Provides initial MethodLogger for new instances of a class"""
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        method_logger = MethodLogger(instance)
        setattr(instance, method_logger_names[cls], method_logger)
        return method_logger

def wrap(function, method_logger_name, needs_self):
    """Wraps a function and in a logging function, and makes the wrapper
    appear as the original function."""
    if needs_self:
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if getattr(self, method_logger_name).record:
                getattr(self, method_logger_name).function = function
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    else: 
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if getattr(self, method_logger_name).record:
                getattr(self, method_logger_name).function = function
            return function(*args, **kwargs) 
    wrapper.__name__ = getattr(function, "__name__", str(function))
    wrapper.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    return wrapper


# used to store name where the method logger is stored for each class
method_logger_names = {}


def record(attr, value, record_hidden, types=FunctionType):
    """Returns whether an attribute is a method and should be logged.
    Never returns true for "dunder" attributes (names beginning with __)"""
    return isinstance(value, types) and not attr.startswith("__") and \
        (record_hidden or not attr.startswith("_"))


def get_superclass_functions(cls, include_hidden, include_callable):
    """Finds all functions derived from the superclasses of a class. Gives
    the name under which the function was found and the function itself.

    Returns tuples of (attribute name, function, if the function needs an
    object instance). If `include_callable' is False then the the function 
    always needs an object instance."""
    base_types = FunctionType if not include_callable else Callable
    attrs = set(vars(cls).keys())
    for superclass in cls.mro()[1:-1]: # exclude actual class and object
        types = (base_types if not hasattr(builtins, superclass.__name__) else 
            Callable)
        for attr, value in vars(superclass).items():
            if attr not in attrs and record(attr, value, include_hidden, types):
                attrs.add(attr)
                yield attr, value, (isinstance(value, FunctionType) or 
                    hasattr(builtins, superclass.__name__))
```

Example usage:

```
class MethodLoggerList(list, metaclass=MethodLoggerMetaclass, 
                       name="_method_logger", record_superclass=True):
    def f(self, kwarg="keyword argument"):
        print(self, kwarg)
    def g(self):
        pass

# example use
t = MethodLoggerList()
print(t._method_logger)
t.f()
t.f("another value")
print(t._method_logger)

# note that methods on superclass are not recorded by default
t.append(0)
print(t._method_logger)
# won't record dunder/magic methods at all
t += [1]
print(t._method_logger)

# stop recording
t._method_logger.record = False
t.g()
print(t._method_logger)

# add methods to class after class creation, and still record them
def h(self):
    pass
MethodLoggerList.h = h
t._method_logger.record = True
t.h()
print(t._method_logger)

# also records lambdas
MethodLoggerList.i = lambda self: None
t.i()
print(t._method_logger)

# does not record monkey-patched methods
def j():
    pass
t.j = j
t.j()
print(t._method_logger)

# does record method or function access from _last_method
method = t._method_logger.method
t.g()
method()
print(t._method_logger)
```